# MEV-BOOST: Cannot connect to Builder

Tags: go-ethereum, docker, goerli, beacon-nodes, mev-boost

I am trying to experiment with mev-boost on goerli testnet but I am getting connection error in my beacon node log.

MEV boost command:

```
sudo docker run flashbots/mev-boost -goerli  -relay-check -relays=https://0xafa4c6985aa049fb79dd37010438cfebeb0f2bd42b115b89dd678dab0670c1de38da0c4e9138c9290a398ecd9a0b3110@builder-relay-goerli.flashbots.net
```

Here are my logs:

```
time="2022-09-16T10:29:57Z" level=info msg="mev-boost v0.8.2" module=cli
time="2022-09-16T10:29:57Z" level=info msg="Using genesis fork version: 0x00001020" module=cli
time="2022-09-16T10:29:57Z" level=info msg="using 1 relays" module=cli relays="[{0xafa4c6985aa049fb79dd37010438cfebeb0f2bd42b115b89dd678dab0670c1de38da0c4e9138c9290a398ecd9a0b3110 https://0xafa4c6985aa049fb79dd37010438cfebeb0f2bd42b115b89dd678dab0670c1de38da0c4e9138c9290a398ecd9a0b3110@builder-relay-goerli.flashbots.net}]"
time="2022-09-16T10:29:57Z" level=info msg="Checking relay" module=service relay="https://0xafa4c6985aa049fb79dd37010438cfebeb0f2bd42b115b89dd678dab0670c1de38da0c4e9138c9290a398ecd9a0b3110@builder-relay-goerli.flashbots.net"
time="2022-09-16T10:29:58Z" level=info msg="listening on localhost:18550" module=cli
```

Its clear that mev-boost client is running on localhost:18550.

This is my Beacon node command on Goreli-Prater test net

```
docker run -d -it -v /home/lucy/launch/prysm:/root -v /home/lucy/launch/geth/genesis.ssz:/genesis.ssz -v /home/lucy/launch/jwt.hex:/jwt.hex -p 4000:4000 -p 13000:13000 -p 12000:12000/udp --name beacon --net=host gcr.io/prysmaticlabs/prysm/beacon-chain:stable --datadir=/root --genesis-state=/genesis.ssz --accept-terms-of-use=true --rpc-host=0.0.0.0 --monitoring-host=0.0.0.0 --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551 --jwt-secret=/jwt.hex --suggested-fee-recipient=0x7Db8bD7FF6a856c1715a58BB4fd83BF43519bDa3 --http-mev-relay=http://localhost:18550  --prater
```

Here is the logs of error after running the above beacon node command

```
Running on the Prater Testnet
[2022-09-16 10:34:28]  WARN flags: Enabled feature flag enable-only-blinded-beacon-blocks=Enables storing only blinded beacon blocks in the database without full execution layer transactions
[2022-09-16 10:34:28]  INFO node: Checking DB database-path=/root/beaconchaindata
[2022-09-16 10:34:28]  INFO db: Opening Bolt DB at /root/beaconchaindata/beaconchain.db
[2022-09-16 10:34:29]  INFO node: Deposit contract: 0xff50ed3d0ec03ac01d4c79aad74928bff48a7b2b
[2022-09-16 10:34:38]  INFO p2p: Running node with peer id of 16Uiu2HAm2BhfednXjfzBqjYPUWufdBKDVtNdAFoTCWEHMUqVMMzw 
[2022-09-16 10:34:38]  INFO blockchain: --weak-subjectivity-checkpoint not provided. Prysm recommends providing a weak subjectivity checkpoint for nodes synced from genesis, or manual verification of block and state roots for checkpoint sync nodes.
[2022-09-16 10:34:38]  INFO initial-sync: Waiting for state to be initialized
[2022-09-16 10:34:38] ERROR main: could not connect to builder: Get "http://localhost:18550/eth/v1/builder/status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:18550: connect: connection refused
```

Here are the logs of my Geth Execution client

```
docker run -d -it -v /home/lucy/launch/geth:/root -v /home/lucy/launch/geth/genesis.ssz:/genesis.ssz -v /home/lucy/launch/jwt.hex:/jwt.hex -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 --name geth --net=host ethereum/client-go --datadir=/root --http --http.port=8545 --http.addr=127.0.0.1 --http.vhosts=* --http.api=eth,net,web3,personal --authrpc.port=8551 --authrpc.vhosts=localhost --authrpc.jwtsecret=/jwt.hex -cache 3072 --goerli
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
db7772106677ea5a716590df2a8ec089015ac32cb5eb9539b9edf56d626eed58
(base) lucy@lucy-Legion-5-Pro-16ITH6H:~/launch$ docker logs -f geth
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.492] Starting Geth on Görli testnet... 
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.493] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.494] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.496] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.498] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=460.00MiB dirty=768.00MiB
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.498] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/geth/chaindata cache=1.50GiB handles=524,288
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.625] Opened ancient database                  database=/root/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain readonly=false
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.625] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=5 dbversion=<nil>
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.625] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.631] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=361 size=51.17KiB time="547.369µs" gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.631]  
INFO [09-16|09:46:52.631] ------------------------
```

Am i missing any command on mev-boost client or beacon node?
Why my beacon node cannot connect to mev client?
Is this docker connection issue?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tweak how networking work across your various docker standalone containers. This line here tells us that your beacon node cannot reach your mev-boost process:

```
[2022-09-16 10:34:38] ERROR main: could not connect to builder: Get "http://localhost:18550/eth/v1/builder/status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:18550: connect: connection refused
```

By default, [the bridge network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) will be used when starting a docker standalone container. If you start your mev-boost docker standalone containers like you are doing right now, it will live on its own isolated network island. To fix this issue, you might need to start it using [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

That would mean starting mev-boost with something like:

```
sudo docker run --network host flashbots/mev-boost -goerli  -relay-check -relays=https://0xafa4c6985aa049fb79dd37010438cfebeb0f2bd42b115b89dd678dab0670c1de38da0c4e9138c9290a398ecd9a0b3110@builder-relay-goerli.flashbots.net
```